# How can I minimise all GNOME/Wayland windows from the command line?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, wayland

Before switching to Wayland I would minimise all GNOME Shell windows with the following command:

```
wmctrl -k on
```

...but both `wmctrl` and `xdotool` are X11-only applications. What CLI command can I use to minimise all windows in a GNOME Shell / Wayland session?

References:

- [Can I minimize a window from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4876) (Ask Ubuntu)

Comment: I know at least on Ubuntu with GNOME you can use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kdb>D</kbd> to minimize all windows.

Comment: @ShaneBishop Gnome 44.1 doesn't detect the Super + D shortcut, in 'custom shortcuts' the combination doesn't return any conflicts with existing native hotkeys. Fedora 38.

Answer (score 5):

## Update

Sadly, this [no longer works on Gnome 41 for security reasons](https://www.reddit.com/r/gnome/comments/pneza1/gdbus_call_for_moving_windows_not_working_in/)

Running `global.context.unsafe_mode = true` in Looking Glass re-enables the functionality, but only temporarily.

## Original answer

As in [my other answer regarding `wmctrl`](https://superuser.com/a/1627429/126557), we can use GJS through `gdbus` in Gnome to do this:

```bsh
gdbus call \
  --session \
  --dest org.gnome.Shell \
  --object-path /org/gnome/Shell \
  --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval \
  "global.get_window_actors().forEach(w=>w.meta_window.minimize())"
```

Answer (score 1):

I will describe a workaround that works for me on my playground Manjaro machine with GNOME3/Wayland. **Keep in mind that the process may slightly differ on other distributions.**

It is not as perfect [as I imagined](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635166/how-to-perform-action-bound-to-a-keyboard-shortcut-in-gnome-from-terminal), but it works.

#### ydotool

In this method, I will use [ydotool](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool). From [README.md](https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool/blob/master/README.md):

> ydotool works differently from xdotool. xdotool sends X events
> directly to X server, while ydotool uses the uinput framework of Linux
> kernel to emulate an input device.

1. **Install it** accordingly to your distribution - [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ydotool/), [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy/ydotool), [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ydotool), etc...
2. You may need to properly **set access rights** for `/dev/uinput` and allow the user to access this device. In this case, add a user to the `users` group and create udev rules file:

**Add yourself to users group**:

```
usermod -a -G users $USER
```

**Create `/etc/udev/rules.d/80-uinput.rules` file** with following content:

```
KERNEL=="uinput", GROUP="users", MODE="0660", OPTIONS+="static_node=uinput"
```

3. You need to **start `/usr/bin/ydotoold` socket listener**. For testing purposes start in manually, but you probably want to **autostart** this **on login**.
4. GNOME 3 allows you to set a keyboard shortcut to "Hide all normal windows". Go to the **`gnome-control-center`**, **Keyboard Shortcuts**, Navigation, **Hide all normal windows**. Set this shortcut, for example, to <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.
5. Now, if everything works as expected, you should be able to minimise all GNOME/Wayland windows with the following command:

```
ydotool key Super+D
```

#### wtype

Another method could be to use [wtype](https://github.com/atx/wtype). It seems to use a different approach and provides keyboard events directly to the compositor. The problem is I was not able to make this work with GNOME's default compositor [mutter](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter). It may be related to the limitations of [XWayland](https://wiki.gnome.org/Initiatives/Wayland/XWayland) but I'm not sure about this. All I get is the error:

> Compositor does not support the virtual keyboard protocol

Comment: I wonder why no one use `sudo addgroup $USER users`, much more friendly

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR You can still do that

While `xdotool` uses X11 APIs and therefore will not work on Wayland, `wmctrl` interacts with the desktop environment itself. Therefore, while its commands requiring X11 APIs will not work, you can still use many `wmctrl` commands in a Wayland session, `-k on` included.

Tested on Arch Linux using GNOME Shell 3.30.2 and `wmctrl` 1.07.

Comment: It only works with X windows, wayland native applications are not supported (listed).

Comment: Wayland is just protocol that simplifies the graphics stack. Many "applications" are in process of being ported from X to Wayland. May be this wmctrl is connected to XWayland. I am not sure where that function call take place but it did work for me.