# How to perform action bound to a keyboard shortcut in Gnome from terminal?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3, gnome-shell, d-bus

How can I perform an action of any Gnome 3 keyboard shortcut in the terminal?

**For example:**

I can use `dconf-editor` to navigate through all keyboard shortcuts and get the dconf path. Let's say:

```
/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/always-on-top
```

Now, I would like to perform wm action that is bound to this from the terminal. I know I can set the actual shortcut and then invoke it with `xdotool key`, but this is not what I want. `xdotool` is more of a workaround then solution, and it only works for X11, not Wayland.

Is there any *non-xdotool* way (for example dbus/gdbus) how to do this?